# If Zn converges in probability to b and g continous function, then g(Zn) converges to g(b)

Tags: probability, continuity, random-variables

If $Z_n \rightarrow b$ in probability $p$, and if $g(z)$ is a function that
is continuous at $z = b$, then $g(Z_n) \rightarrow g(b)$ in probability $p$.

It is pretty clear that we have to use the definition of continuity, but I am having problems finish the exercise. I have seen a solution where the author uses that $Pr(|g(Z_n)-g(b)| < \epsilon) \geq Pr(|Z_n-b| < \delta)$ where $\epsilon,\delta$ come from the definition of continuity. Why is this statement true?

Is there any other way to show the exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the fact that $A \subseteq B$ implies $P(A) \leq P(B)$. From the way $\delta$ is chosen in terms of $\epsilon$ we see that the event $|Z_n-b| <\delta$ is contained in the event $|g(Z_n)-g(b)| <\epsilon$. 
There is no better way to prove this.

Comment: I see. I intuitively understand that inclusion, but is there any specific way to explain $|Z_n-b| <\delta$ as a set?

Comment: All you need is the fact that if $\omega$ is a sample point and $|Z_n(\omega) -b| <\delta$ then $|g(Z_n(\omega)) -g(b)| <\epsilon$. @vicase98

Comment: Shorthand notation for $\{\omega: |Z_n(\omega)-b| < \delta\}$

Comment: Now I see it. Thanks